# Google plus API for WP7 using C#, .NET

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Does google plus provide an API for WP7 to access its services via C# , .NET Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) is just HTTPS requests really, so you could do it manually if you wanted.

There's a [beta version of a .NET client library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) available for general access to Google services, but I don't know offhand whether it would work with WP7 - it may well perform synchronous web requests etc. It's worth a look (and putting in a feature request if it doesn't work with WP7 already) but if it *doesn't* work, then just making the HTTPS calls yourself shouldn't be too hard.

(Disclaimer: I work for Google, but have had nothing to do with this API.)

Comment: There's an issue in the tracker for WP7 support: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=114

Comment: thanks for your inputs jon. I checked out the API page and it has good information about the API. But I would like to know how Google+ API performs authentication using OAuth1.0 and API key.

Comment: @Mugu: Given the docs, it looks like it requires OAuth 2.0, not 1.0.

Comment: any idea how to do the authentication for OAuth2.0 for Google+ API

Comment: sorry managed to form the URL to get the access token from Google+ API . Thanks for your inputs

Comment: I have formed the URL to get access token from Google+ API. Any idea how to get the access token in the code via httpwebrequest or webclient.

Comment: @Mugu: It's not clear what you mean - surely you just make the request and use the response...

Comment: my question was how to make the request from C# code. Currently I m manually copying the URL to my browser and getting the access token.

Comment: @Mugu: Okay, that's a rather different question - and one which doesn't have a lot to do with Google+, really. Given how prevalent web requests are within Windows Phone 7 apps, I suggest you find a tutorial which gives you some guidance. The tricky bit is doing everything asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

It's in beta: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/

I assume it's supports wp7, but i'm not certain.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, as of 2012.04.21 it does not.