# Share a link on google plus windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, google-plus

I am trying to share a link on my windows phone 8 app.So far i am using the

> ShareLinkTask

but its only for Facebook and twitter. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement it by yourself from scratch. This may help you [Google plus API for WP7 using C#, .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016721/google-plus-api-for-wp7-using-c-net)